# How to animate plt.imshow with text?

Tags: python-3.9, matplotlib-animation

I am trying to animate a simulation. I want to include the time of the simulation. I have written the following code:

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ims = []
for i in range(40):
    im=plt.imshow(np.log10(D[0,i,:,:]),cmap=plt.get_cmap("Spectral"),extent=[0,28,0,14],animated=True)
    plt.text(10,2,"t="+str(t[i])+"Myr",c='w',fontsize='large')
    ims.append([im])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)

ani.save("rhdjet1.mp4")
plt.show()
```

But all the text is getting dumped at once in the beginning.[This is a still from the animation. The gibberish in white is the text getting overlayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIBpD.png)
How to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the celluloid package in python:

```
from celluloid import Camera

#Creating matplotlib figure and camera object
fig = plt.figure()

camera = Camera(fig)
 
#Looping the data and capturing frame at each iteration
for i in range(0,90):
      plt.imshow(K[i])
      plt.text(str(t[i]))
      camera.snap()
 
#Creating the animation from captured frames
animation = camera.animate(interval = 200, repeat = True,
                           repeat_delay = 500)
animation.save("restart.mp4")
```